# Google docs: Search+replace external data with cURL

Tags: bash, curl, google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

I have a google docs template and I would like to replace some strings from the template with external data, preferably via cURL as the script that should do the changes is a bash script.

I have the search and replace in google app script done like the one below but I don't know how to call the script and replace with some external data instead.

```
function myFunction() {

var doc = DocumentApp.openById("DOCUMENT_ID");   

  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var client = {
    name: 'Some name',
    address: 'Some address'
  };

  body.replaceText('{name}', client.name);
  body.replaceText('{address}', client.address);
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I created the following google apps script:

```
function doPost(e) {
  var body = DocumentApp.openById("JYOfA_Uv5fxLFA84g11H9XsizHo3F7e1FvSs3EG1vvo").getBody();
  var client = new Function("return " + e.postData.contents)();
  body.replaceText('{name}', client.name);
  body.replaceText('{address}', client.address);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("Done.")
}
```

The cURL command I'm running is:

```
curl -L -d '{"name":"hello","address":"world"}' 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxF_1gddelneCdWCsFcvqT1OgU2zqkjTKSEIulSQfXjfgx1rnY/exec'
```

And the document that the google apps script calls basically has the information {name} and {address}.

The cURL command gives me error that the file could not be found.

The links are accessible as there aren't anything secret there. Only test stuff.

---

**UPDATE 2:**

Link to the test script:
https://script.google.com/a/macros/klarna.com/d/1Q668U_HVtv3T_vQG_39oVL7V5YkcHzYhHUVhR8_XlOmUMRoPf15jDILK/edit?uiv=2&mid=ACjPJvEnpQ77A1Mo4sw8Y5IOPH5Pxs-IxEp1BFpfJU4RsfGXA7HbiHIv23ug_Rw0Y0dPKpWGM_Bb5oVznOqQMeyBki_jQb_g_LafNNPrLM0twO1eyPil3oqR-TjbHA8JToQQk4kdT1eZkE0&splash=yes

Link to the test document:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1JYOfA_Uv5fxLFA84g11H9XsizHo3F7e1FvSs3EG1vvo/edit

Comment: Would you clarify the question, please. Do you want to *access your external data source from within the script* via a cURL-like function? Or, are you trying to *call the bound apps script from an external script* via cURL?

Comment: I want to pass external data from within a cURL-like function and pass it to google docs :)

Answer (score 0):

How about a following sample? I thought of using `doPost()` of Web Apps for your situation. In order to use this sample, please confirm the following flow.

### Flow :

1. Prepare Google Document as a sample. Please put `{name}` and `{address}` in there.
2. Copy and paste the sample script (`doPost(e)`) to your script editor.
3. Deploy Web Apps

   - On the Script Editor
   - Publish

     - Deploy as Web App

       - Create new Project version
       - At Execute the app as, select "your account"
       - At Who has access to the app, select "Anyone, even anonymous"
       - Click "Deploy"
       - Copy "Current web app URL"
       - Click "OK"
4. Please put your endpoint to the sample curl command and run it.

The `Current web app URL` is the endpoint for curl command. The detail information of Web Apps is [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web). **When you modify your script, Web Apps has to be redeployed as a new version.**

#### Sample script :

```
function doPost(e) {
  var body = DocumentApp.openById("DOCUMENT_ID").getBody();
  var client = new Function("return " + e.postData.contents)();
  body.replaceText('{name}', client.name);
  body.replaceText('{address}', client.address);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("Done.")
}
```

At Post method, JSON data can be sent. So I used this. `var client = new Function("return " + e.postData.contents)();` is used for converting from the received string JSON data to an object.

#### Sample curl command :

```
curl -L -d '{name: "Some name", address: "Some address"}' 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/#####/exec'
```

### Note :

This is a simple sample. So when you use this, please modify this to your environment.

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! It looks like the solution I want although something seems wrong, I'm getting "Google Drive - this page could not be found". I've checked the url and it is correct. Will try to see what I'm doing wrong..

Comment: @Kevin I think that there are 2 points for your situation. One is that after Web Apps was deployed, if the script was modified, Web Apps has to be redeployed as a new version. You can see how to deploy it from my answer. Another one is that recently, there are sometimes the cases that such error is returned, when Web Apps was deployed. At that time, I avoid the error by reopening the document with script. I don't know whether your situation is the same to mine. But can you try it? If these were not solutions, I'm sorry. At that time, can you show me your whole script at your shared script?

Comment: @Kevin And then, I have a question for your situation. Is your error the response from curl?

Comment: I updated my first post with the commands I'm running :)
Tried reopening, redeploying as a new version and still getting the same response. The response is from the curl command.

Comment: @Kevin Thank you for adding your additional question. In your case, Web Apps might be not deployed. Can you redeploy it as NEW version?

Comment: I did deploy it as a NEW version, tried again but still the same issue. If I enter the link to my web app in the browser I get "Script function not found: doGet". Does that have anything to do with it?

The error I'm getting when cURLing, I get back response that the address couldn't be found, please try again.

Comment: @Kevin From your error message, it is found that your curl command tries to access to Web Apps using GET method. If you use my sample script, it has to be accessed using POST method. But my curl sample uses POST method. Can I ask you about your curl command? Even if you use my curl sample, when such error occurs, please try to add "-X POST" to the curl command.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! Still didn't work although I will try going in another direction and move the process into confluence instead.

Comment: @Kevin I'm sorry for the inconvenience. I don't know about your current situation. Can you show us your detail current situation to your question?

Comment: I'm updating the question at the end with links to my script and doc I'm editing! :)

Comment: Please check the links under UPDATE 2

Comment: @Kevin For Web Apps, at ``Execute the app as:``, please modify from ``User accessing the web apps`` to ``Me``. And at ``Who has access to the app:``, please modify from ``Anyone`` to ``Anyone. After them, please redeploy as a new version. I think that this was the reason of the error.